# Edit Control Text Changed Message in C++\Win32

Tags: .net, c++, winapi, message

What is the Message that matches the TextChanged property in .NET for C++\Win32?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the [Edit control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775458(VS.85).aspx), [`EN_CHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761676(v=VS.85).aspx) is the notification you're looking for. The parent of the Edit control receives the notification via the [`WM_COMMAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647591(v=VS.85).aspx) message, with `HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE`, `LOWORD(wParam) == edit control identifier` and `lParam == edit control HWND`.