# c++ how to get text from textbox by a thread using win32 api

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, user-interface, textbox

i know how to build a gui application and how to make a textbox i just don't know how to get the data from the textbox without clicking on a bottom (a thread) ?

i there a function to add that i can add in WM_CREATE or what ?

```
    case WM_CREATE:
        CreateWindow ("edit", 0, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 5, 5, 130, 20, hwnd, (HMENU) 1000, GetModuleHandle (NULL), NULL);
        CreateWindow ("button", "Click me", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 5, 30, 130, 20, hwnd, (HMENU) 1001, GetModuleHandle (NULL), NULL);
        break;
```

Comment: To click on a button is unrelated with threads...anyway using GetWindowText() function.

Comment: Guess you are looking for that:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435730/edit-control-text-changed-message-in-c-win32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are using the term thread correctly. Normally you would get text from a text box when the text box sends a message telling you that the user changed the text. Add a case to your windproc that detects the WM_COMMAND message, and look in this message for an EN_CHANGE notification from the text box.

Comment: yes i want to do that when a user change the text in the textbox the case in the WM_COMMAND start to run my code :)
but how to add a case to windproc that detects the WM_command message and look for an EN_CHANGE ?!! sorry i'm a begineer in gui programming

Comment: I'm afraid there is a lot to learn for you; too much to cover in an answer here. Please get a book or find a tutorial about Windows API. Sorry if this sounds rude. Look e.g. here:  
http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/  
Section 9 covers control notifications.

Answer (score 0):

In pure Windows API the text of a window (including text boxes) can be retrieved using the [WM_GETTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message. There are many more messages specific to [text boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: i know about WM_GETTEXT but how to make it in a thread ?!

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you actually want. Do you want, in one thread, to get the text of a edit box that was created in a different thread? You can still use GetWindowText or WM_GETTEXT for this. Or do you want to handle change notifications like EN_CHANGE of the box in a different thread?

Comment: i made a program that get the text when i press a botton, i searched and i found i can only get the text automaticley only with a thread. and i don't know how to put GetWindowText in a thread ?

Comment: it seem like there's a function that can indicate if the text changed (EN_CHANGE) and i can do that without a thread as you say, but how to write the code of EN_CHANGE ?